# How to change raspberry pi 2 overclock to default on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspi-config

I've been wondering how I could reset my raspberry pi 2 to its stock clock after I used the `raspi-config` utils. The only options I had were primarily for the first Raspberry. There's no "default" value for the Pi2.

Something like this:

```
Chose overclock preset                                                       

 None    700MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 400MHz SDRAM, 0 overvolt                     
 Modest  800MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 400MHz SDRAM, 0 overvolt                     
 Medium  900MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 450MHz SDRAM, 2 overvolt                     
 High    950MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 450MHz SDRAM, 6 overvolt                     
 Turbo  1000MHz ARM, 500MHz core, 600MHz SDRAM, 6 overvolt                   
 Pi2    1000MHz ARM, 500MHz core, 500MHz SDRAM, 2 overvolt
```

As you can see, it's possible to overclock the default 900Mhz from the raspberry pi 2, but there's no solution for going back to stock configuration using the `raspi-config` tool. So how on Earth are we supposed to rollback after an overclock?

Comment: It seems like your question has found a happy home here. I think the line between SO and here can be blurry sometimes. If it's a concrete programming question that can theoretically be applied to any Linux platform (or platform-independent), it's a good candidate for SO. If it's a non-programming but still general Linux question, unix.se is nice. Otherwise this site is probably a good fit. A lot of the sites have fuzzy overlap.

Comment: It's good to know it has. It was badly received on stackoverflow. And instead of simply pointing that out, someone started a witch hunt against me, lol. But I'm glad I could help someone with a problem that I faced, and probably many people do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some digging, I found a rather simple solution. You'll have to edit your `config.txt` file. Located on the FAT partition of your raspberry pi SD card.
It's perfectly possible to do it using the pi itself, or you could just plug the microSD card on your computer and use your favorite editor for this.

Ok, now to the configurations...

I'm assuming you're using the raspibian with the command line, but again, you can do this with any text editor.

First, obviously, open the `config.txt` file. It's located on the path `/boot/config.txt`.

E.G.: `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

With your file open, try to find those lines:

```
arm_freq=1000
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=500
over_voltage=2
```

Change those with these ones:

```
arm_freq=900 
core_freq=250 
sdram_freq=450
```

And this line on the file:

```
over_voltage=2
```

Just comment it to be like this, or erase it:

```
#over_voltage=2
```

For more information about overclocking your raspberry pi (Version 1 or 2, model A or B) refer to [this link](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Overclocking). And if you want to learn a little more about the configuration file itself, use the [official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).

I hope this Q/A post helps someone. Thanks for your attention, and happy coding ;)

Comment: So basically the "Medium" setting in raspi-config, minus the overvoltage :) Curious why the Raspberry foundation didn't include this in raspi-config ...

Comment: Indeed. But look at the bright side, the raspi-config tool is open source, so we could actually reprogram it to our needs